# How to get AsyncImage url path from url with SwiftUI

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

My SwiftUI app displays images from an external url properly using

```
            LazyVGrid(columns: columns, alignment: .center, spacing: 10) {
                ForEach(0..<14) { i in
                    AsyncImage(url: url) { image in
                        VStack {
                            image
                                .resizable()
                                .scaledToFill()
                                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
                                .cornerRadius(10)
                                .onTapGesture {
                                    selectedItem = ImageSelection(name: url!.path)
                                    print(selectedItem?.name as Any)
                                 }   
                             }
                        }
            .sheet(item: $selectedItem) { item in
                    Image(item.name)
                       
            }
```

But the sheet that comes up from the `.onTapGesture` is blank. How can I properly get the url path so the image displays on the new sheet? Thanks!

EDIT
Ultimately this view is displaying images from https://picsum.photos. I'm trying to determine the actual URL of the displayed images.

Comment: Use `AsyncImage` with URL in sheet as well.

Comment: It seems unlikely that you should be using the `url`'s `path` to load the image (unless it exists in your bundle). Is the `url` a remote URL?

Comment: Correct, it’s a remote URL that is different per image displayed.

Comment: @Asperi's suggestion is correct, then. The `Image` initializer you're using is for local images inside your app's bundle.

Comment: I don’t think I want to use AsyncImsge in the sheet as well because I want to get the unique image data based on the user interaction. That way I can also allow the user to download the image directly or visit the url

Comment: Hmm, ok I’ll play around with that and report back! Thanks!

Comment: So simply using AsyncImage(url: url) works in the sheet, however it's a random image (just like the view is up top - the images are randomly generated each time the view appears). Which is why I'm trying to get the \.self id of each image. Does that make sense? Thanks!

Comment: `.self` doesn't have anything to do with the uniqueness of the image if it's really the same URL returning different images (as suggested by your code). You'd need unique URLs.

Comment: Thanks @jnpdx, you are absolutely right the url is a picsum url. Ultimately I'm trying to determine the unique url of the individual images being returned into my LazyVGrid.

Comment: It looks like it is all the *same* url. Unless that url maybe returns a redirect? In that case, you’d need to manually parse the HTTP response.

Comment: Yes I believe that's what's needed. Thanks!

Comment: Another thought... if I use the url structure "https://picsum.photos/id/xxx/200/300" where xxx could be any number... Could I potentially have a ForEach loop iterate through that url but add "1" for xxx, then "2", and so on up to a specified point? Like if I had 'let n = [1...100]' then use "https://picsum.photos/id/n/200/300" ?

Answer (score 0):

as `@Asperi` mentioned, you could use another `AsyncImage` to again download the image. Try the following code, which
fixes some of the inconsistencies in your code and also loops over
the url id (as per your latest thought) to download each different ones:

```
struct ImageSelection: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var url: URL?  // <-- note
}

struct ContentView: View {
    let columns:[GridItem] = Array(repeating: .init(.flexible(), spacing: 5), count: 3)
    
    @State var selectedItem: ImageSelection?
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVGrid(columns: columns, alignment: .center, spacing: 10) {
                ForEach(0..<14) { i in
                    let url = URL(string: "https://picsum.photos/id/\(i)/200")
                    AsyncImage(url: url) { phase in
                        if let image = phase.image {
                            image
                                .resizable()
                                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
                                .cornerRadius(10)
                                .onTapGesture {
                                    selectedItem = ImageSelection(url: url)
                                }
                        }
                        else {
                            Image(systemName: "smiley")
                                .resizable()
                                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 50))
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .sheet(item: $selectedItem) { item in
                AsyncImage(url: item.url)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Appreciate the input @dudette! I did make some progress of which I'll update later today, and will certainly play with your suggestion as well!